# How to lock action when button is pressed?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm making a word game, there are three hints, that each cost 10 coins, lets say the player only has 8 coins, then he cannot use 2nd and 3rd hint,

Thus how would I block the action when the hint button is clicked: so that it doesn't show the hint or it doesn't change to the other button image

Code:

```
- (IBAction)secondHintq:(id)sender {
// - Here image is changing when button is clicked - this has to be locked
[_candletwo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"candle2_03.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// This is the text that is displayed when clicked - this has to be locked
hintView.text = @"Type in text here 2";
if(!btn2Pressed) {
    if((coins -10) >= 0){
        coins = coins -10;
        score = score -2;
        btn2Pressed = true;
        coinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",coins];
    }
    else{
        //Show an alert that the user has not enough coins
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TITLE" message:@"MESSAGE" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"RETURN BUTTON" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
   }
```

How is this done?

Comment: is sequence of pressing one of these hint button matters in your Game ?

Comment: yes, there is the main button which is disabled after its tapped, then there are 3 candles that pop up evey time the previous is tapped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your code maybe?

```
if((coins -10) >= 0){
[_candletwo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"candle2_03.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// This is the text that is displayed when clicked - this has to be locked
hintView.text = @"Type in text here 2";
}
```

Comment: clever, I never thought of that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Remove` your `target action` of `button` when not need to `excute` like this :

```
[yourBtn removeTarget:self action:@selector(secondHintq:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

Add target when needed like this :

```
[yourBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(secondHintq:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

**EDIT** : Best option use `userInteractionEnabled property`. These disallow any selection on button

```
yourBtn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Answer (score 0):

```
//Check for coints validity in any button tap event

- (BOOL)checkValidCoins {
    if(coins>=10) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (IBAction)secondHintq:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    if([self checkValidCoins] && !btn.selected) {
        hintView.text = @"Type in text here 2";
        [_candletwo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"candle2_03.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        coins -= 10;
        score -= 2;
        btn.selected = YES;
        coinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",coins];
    }else{
        if(btn.selected) {
            // Show an alert that the user has not enough coins
        }else{
            // Hint already visible
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could toggle the button.enabled property like this:

```
button.enabled = NO
```